# How can I perform infinite Kafka polling using Reactor?

Tags: apache-kafka, project-reactor

What is the reactive way to implement an infinite polling loop using Reactor?
Ideally I would like to send messages from the Producer application and the Consumer application should listen infinitely and process the Flux of messages in the same way every time it receives one, and send the Flux of results back. Do i need a blocking loop or is there a way to keep a publisher alive that can receive a flux process it and send it back?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use processors 
when receiving data from kafka send it to a processor

```
      DirectProcessor <Strings> directProcessor = DirectProcessor.create();
    directProcessor.subscribe();

    public void itemEmitt(String string){
        directProcessor.onNext(string);
    }
```

now directprocessor is a flux that is infinitely listening for event and emitting event